# How do I estimate a variogram for data on a globe?

Tags: r, spatial, geor

I have data with associated longitudes and latitudes.  How do I get a variogram for this data based on the great-circle distances between the points?

This simple example has all the data on the equator:

```
require(geoR)

long <- seq(-179, 180)
x <- sin(pi * long / 180) + rnorm(length(long))
V <- variog(data=x, coords=cbind(long, 0))
# variog: computing omnidirectional variogram
plot(V)
```

The first and last points are actually only 1 degree apart, but my naive attempt results in `variog` thinking they're separated by 359 degrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [Semi-variogram from nmle](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/nlme/html/Variogram.html). It allows you to specify a distance matrix, which you can trivially work out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

From a post on R-sig-geo (mailing list dedicated to spatial data in R) I seem to remember that there are no ready-to-go functions in R that support great circle distances:

http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/Great-Circle-distances-in-Automap-Gstat-td6863940.html

My suggestion would be to project your data and than perform interpolation on the projected data.

Comment: As far as I know there are no distance-preserving projections.

Comment: Your goal is to interpolate a global dataset? Maybe post a question on the R-sig-geo mailing list.

Comment: No, I want to plot a variogram.  Nothing to do with interpolation.

Comment: And projecting your data is not an option? I would imagine you could get some error during projection, but how much would this influence the general trend in the variogram.

Comment: That's only an option if I can find a suitable projection.